# How to find entries without parents in self-referential has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

Two models with the first being self-referential:

```
def Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :source_page_relations,
           :class_name => 'PageRelation',
           :foreign_key => :child_id,
           :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :child_page_relations,
           :class_name => 'PageRelation',
           :foreign_key => :parent_id,
           :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :children, :through => :child_page_relations
  has_many :parents, :through => :source_page_relations
end

def PageRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  belongs_to :child,  :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => :child_id
end
```

Which means I can easily find both parents and children through @page.parents and @page.children.
Now, here's the question: How do I find the "orphans" (or trunks, if you want to go tree-style, i.e. without parents) and the dead-ends (or leafs, i.e. without children) on a global basis?
I'm not that firm in SQL, so maybe someone has a fast idea how to accomplish that instead of a brute-force approach which iterates over all the pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**

wait a minute ; there is, actually, a solution : use a left outer join.

```
Page
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN page_relations ON pages.id = page_relations.child_id")
  .where("page_relations.child_id IS NULL")
```

this, for instance, will find all trunk pages (just joins all pages with their "parent" associations, and select pages with no association).

i don't know what impact it will have on performance, though ; i think it should be reasonably <strike>fast</strike> not too slow, but not to use as a common task. Maybe it would be simpler using an Arel Table (but i'm not familiar enough with these, sadly).

---

i don't know if there is any other way than brute-force iteration here (and if you find one, i'd like to know it).

My advice would be to capture these properties as boolean attributes of the pages and use callbacks to maintain these in a coherent state.

The idea is to add `before_save`, `after_save`, `before_destroy`... callbacks on the `Page` Model, so that every time we manipulate a page, we check if it is a "trunk" or a "leaf" (by checking if it has parents or children via `parents.exist?` and `children.exists?`) ; then we modify boolean `trunk` and `leaf` attributes on this page ( or on the associated page in case of a destroy ).

This will somehow slow down performance on insert / update / delete, but allow to fetch trunks and leaves really fast with a simple  `where( trunk: true )` statement. You will probably have to use `default_scope includes( :parents, :children )` on the `Page` model (or at least use `includes` a lot) to prevent the number of DB hits to explode.

Maybe it's possible to use the same strategy, but to place the callbacks on the `PageRelation` model ; it may even be possible to use an `Observer`. It all depends on your specific needs and coding style, and would be far to long to develop here.

Comment: I think I'll do it like that unless someone comes along with a clever SQL query :)

Comment: finally thought about some SQL query... beware, left outer joins can be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Find the leaves:

```
select * from pages where id not in (select parent_id from page_relations)
```

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS does exactly what you want *(and is less ugly than the right join and does not suffer from the NULL problem like IN)* :

```
SELECT *
  FROM pages pp
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
      FROM page_relations pr
      WHERE pr.child_id = pp.id -- Changed
      )
  ;
```

Update: changed the WHERE condition after @Rhywden's comment.

Comment: Would `select parent_id from page_relations` ever return a NULL value?

Comment: I don't know, I've never seen the table definitions. (that Ruby stuff is unreadable for me, and the semantics may change with the phase of the moon). In most cases the IN () construct is not needed. In most implementations, EXISTS even performs better.

Comment: Little correction, the last WHERE condition needs to be "pr.child_id = pp.id". Other than that, works fine. Will go with the previous JOIN solution, though, since that looks programmatically nicer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the ugly Ruby syntax and snatched the fragments from the other contributions ... (could you **please** post the real table definitions, next time? Most of the ruby people really don't understand SQL, and very few of the SQL people grasp the ruby-syntax)

Comment: "ugly ruby Syntax" ? i'm so shocked i consider flagging this :p. that apart, NOT EXISTS does exactly the same thing as a LEFT OUTER JOIN / IS NULL, at least the query plan is the same in PostgreSQL for all i know ; i chose it because it seemed to integrate a bit better in the "ugly syntax". I'm not a DBA, do you happen to know if EXISTS is well implemented in many DBs ? just to keep this the more db-agnostic possible. For the real table definitions, learn about rails and you should be able to guess them easily :p

Comment: I know that, but the left outer IS NULL is ugly as well (plugging in a NULL where a row does not exist, and than testing for null, looks like egghunting) Besides: the NOT EXISTS-syntax is older, and is implemented better on *some* platforms. The problem with the ruby-syntax: you lose >90 percent of the SQL-competent readers, IMHO (and there are *really* good sql-gurus here) . And it is not ugly, only unreadable ;-)